# ASP.NET MVC and Ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

From what I've read about ASP.NET MVC, it appears it requires posting to work, is there any working example (With source available) of a ASP.NET MVC website that has no postbacks with the help of Ajax?

(I checked the related questions earlier but couldn't find what I was looking for)

Thanks in advance.

edit: I need jQuery solutions not Atlas Toolkit stuff!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from Preview 4...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx

With jquery

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-mvc-submitting-ajax-form-with-jquery.aspx

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, I'm sorry I didn't mention I was looking for jQuery stuff, not the atlas toolkit

Comment: Atlas is so 2006. It is now ASP.NET Ajax :)